# Resharper Rename variable wants to rename all instance of string in file

Tags: rename, resharper

I'm trying to rename a variable that is a parameter to a method (a very small method with just a few lines of code).  Instead of simply renaming the usages of that variable inside the method, Resharper brings up a dialog showing how it wants to rename every instance of that string inside the entire file.

This seems beyond stupid to me.  Why can't Resharper just rename the variable I am trying to rename that is obviously just in that one method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReSharper has two rename workflows: inline rename without a dialog when the changes are limited to a local scope, and global rename with a dialog when changes might be made to multiple files. Unfortunately because of [named arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) renaming a method parameter is a global rename, since ReSharper might have to change multiple method calls in other files.

Comment: This shouldn't be the right answer. What @Igor says is true in a sense because the `scope` is all files. But that search should only happen in context where the method is being called. What really happens is a blind search and replace - where even if the same text was present in a comment or as another class'es member variable, it will still be included.

Comment: @Mugen I don't understand what you're saying. When renaming a parameter R# will only rename the usages of the parameter. You can enable an option to also look in comments and string literals, in this case R# will show a list of text usages and you'll be able to choose which of them to rename.